# Advanced custom control features in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I'm working on building a custom control. Basically I want to allow the application to generate rectangles (positioned at `x = 0` with a variable `y` value that increases as each rectangle is added).

I'd like them to respond to gestures where they have two positions (closed - which mostly hidden, open - expanded fully so that the entire rectangle is still visible but tethered to the side).

I've already designed an application with this in mind. Seeing as the rectangles will be generated by the users, I assume core graphics would be best for the job. Also, I want the rectangles to display different information based on their gesture-related position.

Is it possible to combine core graphics with these types of controls? I know this is asking a lot.

It's just that I'm having trouble determining how to combine each component in code.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: There is no question in your post.

Answer (score 1):

Clearly, we're not here to write code for you, but a few thoughts:

You say that you assume Core Graphics would be best for the job. You definitely could, but you could also use `CAShapeLayer`, too.

So you might create a gesture recognizer whose handler:

1. Creates a `CAShapeLayer` when the gesture's state is `UIGestureStateBegan` and adds it as a sublayer of the view's `layer`.
2. Replace that shape layer's `path` property with the `CGPath` of a `UIBezierPath` which is created on the basis of updated location that the gesture recognizer handler captures when the gesture's state is `UIGestureStateChanged`.

I'd suggest you take a crack at that (googling "CAShapeLayer tutorial" or "UIPanGestureRecognizer example" or what have you, if any of these concepts are unfamiliar).

If you really want to use Core Graphics, you would have a custom `UIView` subclass whose `drawRect` draws all of the rectangles. Conceptually it's very similar to the above, but you have to also writing your own rectangle drawing code that you'll put in `drawRect`, rather than letting `CAShapeLayer` do that for you.

Comment: Of course and I wasn't asking for anyone to write code for me. That's a great suggestion! I hadn't even considered using  CAShapeLayer. I'll go play around with ways to incorporate that now. Thanks!